# EE3 Multiple database settings without core 'hack'

Tags: database, ee3, development

SO I am trying to build out a master config file to use with deployment similar to that in EE2 for EE3. In the include, I have the following:

```
$config['database'] = array (
    'expressionengine' => array (
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'local-UN',
        'password' => 'local-pw',
        'database' => 'local-db',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => 'exp_',
        'pconnect' => FALSE
    ),
    'localhost' => array (
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'local-UN',
        'password' => 'local-pw',
        'database' => 'local-db',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => 'exp_',
        'pconnect' => FALSE
    ),
    'production' => array (
        'hostname' => 'external-server',
        'username' => 'ext-UN',
        'password' => 'ext-pw',
        'database' => 'ext-db',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => 'exp_',
        'pconnect' => FALSE
    )
);
```

The reason I left the 'expressionengine' database in there is because of the call for it in DBConfig.php which I'll show in a moment. I know the databases are being populated because when I output `print_r(ee()->config->config);` I get the database array as this:

```
[cache_driver] => file
[database] => Array
    (
        [expressionengine] => Array
            (
                [hostname] => localhost
                [username] => local-UN
                [password] => local-pw
                [database] => local-db
                [dbdriver] => mysqli
                [dbprefix] => exp_
                [pconnect] => 
            )

        [localhost] => Array
            (
                [hostname] => localhost
                [username] => local-UN
                [password] => local-pw
                [database] => local-db
                [dbdriver] => mysqli
                [dbprefix] => exp_
                [pconnect] => 
            )

        [production] => Array
            (
                [hostname] => external-server
                [username] => ext-UN
                [password] => ext-pw
                [database] => ext-db
                [dbdriver] => mysqli
                [dbprefix] => exp_
                [pconnect] => 
            )

    )

[db_port] =>
```

The issue I'm having is getting around the following inside the DBConfig.php file:

```
/**
 * ExpressionEngine Database Config Class
 *
 * @package    ExpressionEngine
 * @subpackage Core
 * @category   Core
 * @author     EllisLab Dev Team
 * @link       https://ellislab.com
 */
class DBConfig implements Config {

    protected $delegate;
    protected $active_group;

    protected $defaults = array(
        'port'     => 3306,
        'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => '',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'dbprefix' => 'exp_',
        'swap_pre' => 'exp_',
        'db_debug' => TRUE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'autoinit' => FALSE,
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'cachedir' => '', // Set in constructor
    );

    /**
     * Create new Database Config object
     *
     * @param ConfigFile $config Config\File object
     */
    public function __construct(ConfigFile $config)
    {
        $this->delegate = $config;
        $this->active_group = $this->delegate->get(
            'database.active_group',
            'expressionengine'
        );

        $this->defaults['cachedir'] = rtrim(APPPATH, '/').'/user/cache/db_cache/';
    }
```

Is there a way to dynamically pass the `$active_group` into the DBConfig class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dynamic config, define the `$config['database']['expressionengine']` group conditionally. Have a look TJ Draper's dynamic config, specifically [these lines](https://gist.github.com/tjdraper/d875ecd2809ae52e4254#file-config-php-L28)

```
// Set up the database
$db = array(
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => 'exp_',
    'pconnect' => FALSE
);

// Require environment config file
require 'config.' . ENV . '.php';

// Set the database array to the config
$config['database'] = array (
    'expressionengine' => $db,
);
```

In your `config.foo.php` files, [specify](https://gist.github.com/tjdraper/d875ecd2809ae52e4254#file-config-stage-php-L3) the `$db` array, overriding any settings necessary:

```
$db['username'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$db['password'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$db['database'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

Comment: Right. So the 'active_group' HAS to be 'expressionengine' though? As where in 2, you could specify in the top of the database.php file $active_group = 'expressionengine'; (or whatever else you set in the $db array there.) like: $db['local']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['local']['username'] = ‘mylocaluser’; where you could set it as $active_group = 'local';     Is this right?

Comment: Yep! This way ExpressionEngine only connects through a consistently named group. Having a group _at all_ is a bit of legacy.

Answer (score 1):

@derek-jones Thanks for the nudge... I ended up with the following in mine.

```
/*
|-----------------------------------------------------------
| Database and Multi-environment
|-----------------------------------------------------------
| You can have whatever environments you need.
| First, build out your environment arrays.
| Then set your $active_environment to which you need to use.
*/
    $active_environment = 'production';

    $localhost = array (
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'local-un',
        'password' => 'local-pw',
        'database' => 'local-db',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => 'exp_',
        'pconnect' => FALSE
    );

    $production = array (
        'hostname' => 'remote-host',
        'username' => 'remote-un',
        'password' => 'remote-pw',
        'database' => 'remote-db',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => 'exp_',
        'pconnect' => FALSE
    );

    $config['database'] = array (
        'expressionengine' => $$active_environment
    );
```